# Size of C++ vector is invalid

Tags: c++, vector

The following code is given:

```
#include <vector>
std::vector<int> intVec;
intVec.reserve(5);
intVec[0] = 1;
std::cout << "intVec Size: " << intVec.size();
```

Why does `intVec.size()` returns the invalid size 0? How can I fix that issue? I don't want to use `push_back` instead and also don't want to zero-initialize the vector with 5 elements.

Edit: The size of the vector should be 1 after `intVec[0] = 1`.

Comment: reserve changes capacity not size. Your `intVec` is like empty tank..

Comment: why do you call `0` "invalid". It is completely valid for a vector to have size 0, especially if you neither want to push something into it nor init it with some size other than 0

Comment: `reserve` doesn't change the size. *I don't want to use push_back instead and also don't want to zero-initialize the vector with 5 elements.* What **do** you want?

Comment: Could you specify what you want this code to do so we can help you?

Comment: Tongue-in-cheek answer: if you don't want to use `intVec.push_back(x)`, use `intVec.insert(intVec.end(), x)` instead. More seriously: you need to either pre-initialise the vector to a size, or add elements to it, if you want it to not be empty.

Comment: So your actually goal is making a vector with 5 uninitialized elements, did I get that right?

Comment: Edited my question.

Comment: @user1056903 it seems pretty "abusive" to the vector. why not use push_back or a 0 initalization?

Comment: @user1056903 I'm so confused, I think maybe you want is`intVec.resize(5,1)`.

Comment: I think X-Y problem. If OP says what he want to achieve OR why we he want such thing , we can help better.

Comment: After edit: That's not possible. `std::vector::operator[]` can only access existing elements, it never changes the vector's size.

Comment: If you want the size to be 1 after `intVec[0] = 1;` it also has to be 1 before `intVec[0] = 1;` -  there's no way around that. You can `intVec.resize(1)` first if you're desparate for the indexing operator.

Comment: @user1056903 _he size of the vector should be 1 after `intVec[0] = 1`_ No. What makes you think so? I'd recommend you first consult the [reference documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at) before making wild assumptions.

Comment: This feels like an X-Y problem.  What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to build a circular/ring buffer that is NOT zero-initialized after creation, i.e. no elements should be in the buffer immediately after creation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your non-understable question, I can guess that you want the vector to treat the `[] operator` as "edit if it is exist or create if it is not". Some thing like the behavior of `[] operator` in `std::map` for example..

You simply **can not**. It was not designed like this.

BTW, you may do something like this: (It is bad idea. Do not.)

```
int& funky_operator(std::vector<int>& vec, const std::size_t index){
    if(index<vec.size()){
        vec.resize(index+1);
    }
    return vec[index];
}
int main(){
    std::vector<int> intVec;
    intVec.reserve(5);
    funky_operator(intVec,0) = 1;
    std::cout << "intVec Size: " << intVec.size();
}
```

Again, this is stupid code. Do not use in real life. However, it is what you want.